# CAD, Point Cloud Matching

Tags: ros, cad, model, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have ROS fuerte on my ubuntu 11.10 O.S. .. I have created a point cloud for an object using RoboEarth detector and I want my robot " with a kinect on it " to be able to try matching this point cloud with a CAD Model of the same object or similar, which can be stored in TOD database that is uploaded on (http://www.3d-net.org)
How could I make my robot make this matching ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56101/cad,-point-cloud-matching/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have a look at Point Cloud Librairy, which does it. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/template_alignment.php#template-alignment) for example.

EDIT : also this package [blort_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/blort_ros) in ROS

Bests,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-02-25**:
thanks , I'll have a look on them .